# Unable to print variable having regex match results in Ansible

Tags: regex, exception, ansible, runtime-error, stdout

Below is my playbook which search for string "SSLFile" and stores the matches results in a set_fact called "target"

```
- name: Find certificate entries
  set_fact:
    target: "{{ filecontent.stdout | regex_findall('\\sSSLFile.*') }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ target }}"
```

The above debug output shows three matched lines. See output below:

```
TASK [Find certificate entries] ***************************************
task path: /app/test.yml:908
ok: [10.9.9.11] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "target": [
            " SSLFile  /web/test1.crt", 
            " SSLFile  /web/SSL.crt", 
            " SSLFile  /web/test.crt"
        ]
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

I wish to get only the filenames i.e 2nd column from variable "target" i.e

```
/web/test1.crt
/web/SSL.crt
/web/test.crt
```

I tried the following but none of them works and gives error:

```
    - name: Print found entries
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split()[1] }}"
      with_items: "{{ target.split(',') }}"
```

Also, tried the following:

```
 with_items: "{{ target.results }}"
 with_items: "{{ target.stdout_lines }}"
 with_items: "{{ target.stdout }}"
```

Error recieved:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /app/test.yml:917
fatal: [10.9.9.11]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/test.yml': line 917, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `regex_findall('\\sSSLFile\\s*(.*)')`,  no need for `split`

Comment: How will i then be able to just list the first file "/web/test1.crt" not all the three search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `target` is a list. It's possible to iterate it. The task

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split()[1] }}"
      loop: "{{ target }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "/web/test1.crt"
    "msg": "/web/SSL.crt"
    "msg": "/web/test.crt"
```